# SVN User Password Keeps Resetting

Tags: svn, version-control

I am administrating an svn server.  I create a new repo, and recently users are having a problem with their passwords not working.  It seems that everytime one user commits a file, this knocks out the password for other users. I have to manually reset the user passwords using htpasswd -c /svn/repos/users [user] to restore.

My user file is located at /svn/repors/users.  I seem to recall that in the past if had a list of users and their encrypted passwords. Now it seems to have one one user/password combo.  It looks like the file gets updated with the last user who commits a repository.

I updated the owner and group from root to apache, but that is not solving the problem.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to manually reset the user passwords using `htpasswd -c /svn/repos/users [user]` to restore.

```
$ man htpasswd
```

> -c     Create the passwdfile. If passwdfile already exists, it is **rewritten and truncated**. This option cannot be combined with the -n option.

Stop using `-c` if the file exists, as it removes *all other users*, and all will be well as soon as you've re-added every single user...

Comment: Yeah, I totally missed that (derp!).  I removed -c and now everything is working fine.  Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for your SVN server? `svnserve` or Apache `httpd`?

Where are your repositories located? Is your user file under that same directory structure? That could be a problem.

For example, you have:

```
/svn/repos/project1
/svn/repos/project2
/svn/repos/users
```

And, you're running:

```
$ svn -r /svn/repos -d
```

You could be corrupting your users list because Subversion thinks it's another repository. Move it to another location.

```
$ mv /svn/repos/users /svn/repos/project1/conf
```

Yes, you can safely store your users list under the `conf` directory of any of your repositories. Just make sure that your `svnserve.conf` file for each repository is pointing to the new location.